# how to generation animation as mpg or speed up gif in matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, movie

I am plotting a randomly walking points on the figure and trying to capture the motion at each step by getframe. After I collect all the frames, I output the result as avi with movie2avi, but the output file was so big to fit into my presentation. I am looking for a way to export the movie to mp4, anyone have any idea? I also try to use the 3rd party movie2gif, it save the size to huge extent but when I play the gif, it looks so unsmooth

Comment: The problem with gif generation is that, regardless of the speed you specify for each frame, the viewing platform you use to view the resulting gif may override your settings. This is likely why your resulting gif looks 'unsmooth'.

Comment: Yes, I think so, an even worse when I insert the gif into a powerpoint, some frame pause in the mid way. I am looking for a way to generate a movie in mp4 or other formation with small size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In later versions of Matlab (e.g. 2012) it is done by creating and writing a video object. For example, the following code generates movie of a randomly moving circle. You can adjust the speed of the movie with the `FrameRate` and the size with the `Quality` properties. For more details see the [Matlab documentation.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/reading-and-writing-files.html)

```
vobj=VideoWriter('MyMovieFile', 'Motion JPEG AVI');
vobj.FrameRate=4;
vobj.Quality=75
open(vobj);
for i=1:100
  plot(rand,rand,'o')
  F=getframe(gcf);
  writeVideo(vobj, F);
  cla(gca)
end
close(vobj)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, my matlab is too old. But I try that in my friend's computer with 2012, it works perfectly :)

Comment: In earlier versions you can compress with the 'compression' parameter in movie2avi. It looks like video obbject was introduced with 2010b. See this [video](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/videowriter-object-in-r2010b-69020.html).